# i want to use JavaScript in only mobile (snap.js)

Tags: javascript, mobile

i want to use this javascript in only mobile or screen.width < 768

i tryed to this but action...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mobile-menu/open-left.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mobile-menu/snap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var snapper = new Snap({
        element: document.getElementById('content'),
        disable: 'right'
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width < 980) { 
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mobile-menu/snap.js"></script>');  
 } 
</script>
```

how i can do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come up with this solution:

Open the snap.js file. Copy paste this:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 768) {
//Current snap.js code
;}
```

And it works perfect. But I'm still looking for a way to get this thing working when you resize your window. Now it only takes the start Width of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, this seems to be working for me:

```
function snapperToggler() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        snapper.enable();
    } else {    
        snapper.close();
        snapper.disable();
    }
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    snapperToggler();
});
```